# .env file is ignored and not "sourced" by `docker-compose`

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Case: I start a service in `docker-compose`.
All the variables in the `.env` file are ignored and not dynamically replaced, such as below:

```
PS C:\workarea\jonathan\myProject> docker-compose up -d myService
time="2021-07-23T15:20:50-04:00" level=warning msg="The XXXXX_URL variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-07-23T15:20:50-04:00" level=warning msg="The XXXXX_USER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-07-23T15:20:50-04:00" level=warning msg="The XXXXX_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-07-23T15:20:50-04:00" level=warning msg="The YYYY_URL variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-07-23T15:20:50-04:00" level=warning msg="The ZZZ_URL variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-07-23T15:20:50-04:00" level=warning msg="The XXXXX_URL variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-07-23T15:20:50-04:00" level=warning msg="The XXXXX_USER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-07-23T15:20:50-04:00" level=warning msg="The XXXXX_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-07-23T15:20:50-04:00" level=warning msg="The YYYY_URL variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-07-23T15:20:50-04:00" level=warning msg="The ZZZ_URL variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2021-07-23T15:20:50-04:00" level=warning msg="The DDDDD_ROOT_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
...
```

Environment:

- Windows 10
- Docker Desktop for Windows 3.5.2 (66501)
- WSL 2
- Compose 1.29.2

Comment: Have you tried explicitly referencing the env file with `--env-file=.env`? https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#using-the---env-file--option

Comment: Also, you mention wsl but it isn't relevant here as you're using powershell from NFS.

Comment: Hi @SoftwareEngineer,

* I did try with explicit `--env-file` and explicit `-f`.

* I tried with both WSL, PowerShell and CMD, and the result was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution consists in disabling `Use Docker Compose V2` in Settings > Experimental Features, then "Apply and Restart":
[image]

Warning: although this option is unchecked, Docker happens to re-enable it without any user's action. This occurred to me several times, on two different laptops.

Comment: How does compose v2 interfere with the loading of the environment file?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer that's the point that surprised me.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me :/ Working on macOS 11.4, having same versions of compose and Docker desktop as @JonathanLalou